# Connect to postgres with different privileges

Tags: postgresql

From python program, I want to connect to postgres with various privileges.

```
lower_privileges = connect(db, username, password)
higher_privileges = connect(db, username, password)
```

How do I setup postgres 9.5 on arch linux, so I can do that?

```
create database dbone; 
grant all privileges on dbone.* to 'writer'@'localhost' identified by 'pass';
grant select on dbone.* to 'reader'@'localhost' identified by 'pass';
```

The problem is I enter `createdb dbone` then `psql` then `grant all privileges on database dbone to writer;` and I get "db does not exist error" then I exit psql and go `dropdb dbone` and get "db does not exist"

Comment: Are you asking how to grant various privileges in Postgres? I'm sure this is explained in the manual. If you have a more specific problem, please edit your question.

Comment: Your `GRANT` syntax looks like that of MySQL, but in any case, it's not PostgreSQL.  Or is it just an illustration from your MySQL experience?  If so, then please read carefully the documentation on `GRANT`, as @mustaccio suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [arch guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PostgreSQL#Installing_PostgreSQL)

- `sudo pacman -S postgresql`
- `su - postgres`
- `initdb --locale $LANG -E UTF8 -D '/var/lib/postgres/data'`
- `exit`
- Start postgres service `sudo systemctl start postgres.service`

- Check admin stuff

  - Set postgres system user pass `passwd postgres PASS`
  - `su - postgres`
  - Optional, you could set connection host rules `vim data/pg_hba.conf`
  - `psql`
  - Set admin DB pass `\password PASS`
- Create db `create database dbone;`
- Add users, grant privileges

  - `create user writer --interactive -P;`
    `create user reader --interactive -P;`
  - give all privileges to writer user `grant all privileges on database "dbone" to writer;`
  - Quit `\q`
  - Connect to your db `psql dbone`
  - For tables in the public schema of your db, automatically give select privileges to reader user `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO reader;`
  - `\q`,   `exit`